# Solving $2^x+2^y+1=3^z$ in integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have reasons to believe that there should be an elementary, relatively simple way to find all solutions of the equation in the title in positive integers $x>y$ and $z$. Any ideas?

Comment: $4+4+1=3^2$ is one solution

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's not a solution as it must be $\;x>y,z\;$ .

Comment: Observe that for $\;m\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;2^m=1\iff m\;$ is even, and from here that it must be $\;x,y\;$ even both. For example, one solution is $\;(x,y,z)=(6,4,4)\;$

Comment: If a solution $(x,y,z)$ exists, then $y$ must be ceiling of $z \log_2(3)-1$. The reason is that, on the one hand, $2^y < 3^z$ hence $y < z \log_2(3)$, and on the other hand $2^y \geq 3^z/2$ since $y > x$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: also, it is not difficult to show that $z$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Oops, switched $x$ and $y$ in my previous comment. The idea still holds. Anyway, $(6,4,4)$ is a solution.

Comment: @DonAntonio I guess you mean $2^m=1\pmod 3$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, of course. Thank you, hopefully others will see this.

Comment: For $z < 100000$, I find that $(6,4,4)$ is the only solution.

Comment: We may probably prove that the Hamming weight of $3^z-1$ is always $\geq 3$ for any $z\geq 5$ by exploiting $3^{z+1}-1 = (2+1)\cdot(3^{z}-1)+2.$

Comment: If you have reasons to believe that the equation can be solved elementary, please tell us them. I would consider this equation to be very difficult.

Comment: @W-t-P: why $z$ has to be a multiple of $4$?

Comment: @Peter: it is a non-mathematical reason. This equation was given in a kind of a math / programming summer camp to school students. The instructor said it is a very difficult problem, but what is difficult for a 13-year-old should not be that difficult to the MSE community...

Comment: @JackD'Aruizio: thanks for your interest; I will try to sketch the argument later today.

Comment: If $y\ge3$ then $z$ must be a multiple of $2^{y-2}$ because $3^z\equiv1\pmod {2^y}$ and $3$ is of order $2^{y-2}$ modulo $2^y$. This will force $x$ to be quite large for larger values of $y$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: thanks, this saves me the effort to explain my divisibility claim.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: so, are we stating that the question boils down to showing that $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is a badly approximable number?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Quite possibly! Two of my coworkers published something about the complexity of calculating the first ternary digit of $2^n$, so they might know (even though their task was to approximate $\log2/\log 3$. I'll send an e-mail.

Comment: At this point of time the only thing that can be shown is that (as has been shown earlier ) $x$,$y$ are divisible by 2 and $z$ is divisible by 4. However if $z$ is divisible by 4 and not 8 then $y$ will always be 4 and $x$ will be an even number of the type $4b+2$ where $b$ is an integer. If $z$ is divisible by 8 then it needs a little more study to bring out the relations. I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The reply I got was that they used a consequence of a theorem of Baker stating that
$$|m\ln2-n\ln 3|\ge1/n^C$$ for some constant $C$. Not sure if that is at all useful here. I'm afraid I'm not at all conversant in Diophantine approximation beyond the basics.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: well, that proves that $\log_2(3)$ is badly approximable in some sense, so settles the question.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: well, this may show that there are finitely many solutions, but the question was to find *all* solutions using a *relatively simple  elementary argument*; so, I wouldn't say that the question is settled.

Comment: My colleague came back with the following refinement. In G. Rhin: Approximants de Padé et mesures effectives d’irrationalité.
Séminaire de Théorie des Nombres, Paris 1985–86, 155–164, Progr. Math., 71, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA (1987) it is shown that $C\approx13.3$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was eventually able to recover (?) the elementary solution mentioned in the literature. I will show below that the only solutions in positive integers $x,y,z$ are $x=4,y=6,z=4$, $x=6,y=4,z=4$, and $x=y=z=2$.

Reducing  $2^x+2^y+1=3^z$ modulo $3$, we conclude that both $x$ and $y$ are even; say, $x=2a$ and $y=2b$, leading to $4^a+4^b+1=3^z$. Reducing now modulo $4$ we see that $z$ is even, too, and the substitution $z=2c$ gives $4^a+4^b+1=9^c$.

Assume without loss of generality that $a\le b$. If $a=1$, then $4^b+5=9^c$  whence $b=1$ and therefore also $c=1$, as otherwise reducing modulo $16$ we would get $9^c\equiv 5\pmod{16}$, which is impossible (the order of $9$ modulo $16$ is $2$). Thus $a\ge 2$, and reducing $4^a+4^b+1=9^c$ modulo $16$ we obtain $9^c\equiv 1\pmod{16}$, whence $c$ is even; we write $c=2u$ to get $4^a+4^b+1=81^u$.

We know that $a\ge 2$. If, indeed, $a=2$, then $4^b+17=81^u$, whence $(9^u-2^b)(9^u+2^b)=17$, leading to $u=1,b=3$; that is, $x=z=4$, $y=6$.

We are thus left with the case where $b\ge a\ge 3$. Reducing $4^a+4^b+1=81^u$ modulo $64$ and observing that the order of $81$ modulo $64$ is $4$, we conclude that $u$ is divisible by $4$, whence $4^a+4^b+1=3^{16v}$, $u=4v$. Reducing then modulo $85$ (which is a divisor of $3^{16}-1$), we get $4^a+4^b\equiv 0\pmod{85}$. Dividing through by $4^a$ gives $4^{b-a}\equiv -1\pmod{85}$. However, there is no power of $4$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $85$, as one can easily verify (the order of $4$ modulo $85$ is $4$). This shows that there are no solutions with $a,b\ge 3$.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bunch of considerations for now.

Let we define the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) $H$ of $n$ as the number of bits "1" in the binary representation of $n$. We have, for instance, $H(7)=3$, $H(15)=4$, $H(2^m)=1$. Moreover, let $a_k=3^k-1$. 
We have $a_{k+1}=(2+1)a_k+2$.

> **Claim.** For every $k\geq 5$, $H(a_k)\geq 3. \tag{1}$

If we prove the above claim, we obviously have that $(x,y,z)=(6,4,4)$ is the only solution of the given equation. We may consider that:
$$\begin{array}{rcr} a_4 &=& 1010000_{2}\\ a_5&=&11110010_2\\  a_6&=&1011011000_2\\ a_7&=&100010001010_2\\ a_8&=&1100110100000_2 \\ a_9&=&100110011100010_2\end{array}$$
and that if $a_k\pmod{16}\not\in\{0,1,2,4,8\}$ then $H(a_k)$ is $\geq 3$ for sure. 
The same conclusion holds if $a_k\pmod{32}\not\in\{0,1,2,4,8,16\}$.

If $k$ has to be a multiple of $4$ as stated by W-t-P in the comments and proved by Jyrki Lahtonen,
 it makes sense to set $b_k=a_{4k}$ and prove

> **Claim.** For every $k\geq 2$, $H(b_k)\geq 3. \tag{2}$

maybe through $b_{k+1}=(2^6+2^4+2^0) b_k + (2^6+2^4)$ and/or

$$ \log_2(3) \approx \frac{1623}{1024} = 1.1001010111_2.$$

> The question is indeed settled by [a result of Dubitskas](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper26.ps), giving that the distance of $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k$ from the closest integer is $\geq 2^{-ck}$ with $c\approx 0.793$. Such a result in diophantine approximations follows from the work of Beukers, Thue and Siegel (the hypergeometric method).

Comment: I think I saw an article long ago that implied $H(a_n)$ growed at least as a $O(\log(\log n))$ but I don't have it here >_>

Comment: @mercio: are you able to recover it? That would strike the definitive blow!

Answer (score 1):

The only solutions are given by a comment to equation (8.036) in the article http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1982.101.263 by Brenner and Foster (Pac. J. Math 101 (1982) no 2, p 263-301).

Comment: This is certainly highly relevant, but I am still interested to see an actual elementary solution that a 13-y.-o. can understand. The paper you refer to mentions that "using a few small moduli, L. J. Alex [2b] established that the only solutions are $(a, b, c) = (1, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2), (4, 6, 4)$ or $(4, 4, 6)$" but, frustratingly, the reference [2b] reads "personal communication"! Basically, this confirms my claim that there is a relatively simple solution, but does not provide this solution!

Comment: Are $(1,0,0)$ and $(4,4,6)$ a solutions ?

Comment: @Barun Dasgupta: They listed the values of $z$ first; say, $(1,0,0)$ means $x=y=0$, $z=1$.

Answer (score 0):

@W-t-P  MINOR NIT: There is also the trivial solution $x$=0, $y$=0, $z$=1.  And since the original problem says 'solution in integers', not 'solution in natural numbers', one must also note that there are no solutions containing negative numbers *(because either one gets an equality between an integer and a fraction [on either side], or after one clears fractions one gets an equality between a multiple of a power of three and an exact power of two)*.